# sqlalchemy connection issue while running docker image on local window machine

Tags: windows, sqlalchemy, dockerfile

docker image builds successfully. But when actually I run docker image using docker run command to check if my application works fine. I got the below issue.
Please need guidance over this issue. Thanks a lot

issue:
sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError: (pyodbc.Error) ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/dbapi)

connection string:

```
def connectiondb():
params = urllib.parse.quote_plus(
"DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=servername;DATABASE=dbname;UID=username;PWD=password")
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % params)
metadata = MetaData(engine)
con = engine.connect()



   dockerfile:
FROM python:latest

Bundle app source
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app

Update
RUN pip install --upgrade pip

RUN apt-get update &&
apt-get install -y apt-transport-https &&
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add - &&
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/9/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list &&
apt-get update &&
ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install msodbcsql17 unixodbc-dev -y
RUN apt-get install libssl-dev
RUN pip install pyodbc==4.0.28
RUN pip install numpy==1.18.1
RUN pip install scikit-multiflow==0.4.1
RUN pip install Cython
RUN pip install scikit-learn==0.21.3

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 5000
CMD python ./app.py
return con, metadata,engine
```

Comment: Try using `DRIVER=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server` to specify the driver name.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. It worked for me . atleast image run successfully with docke run  commnad.Only issue now comes is login time out exception